# reload tableview without hiding keyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a custom table view cell that's the first cell in my table view, in which I have a textfield I'm trying to make function like a search feature.
I want the data in the remainder of the table view to update as the user types. I have the search cell's textField set up via .addTarget to trigger EditingChanged so every time the user types something new into the textField it will show the updated results. But it seems that calling self.tableView.reloadData() triggers EditingDidEnd and hides the keyboard, after each letter.

Via addTarget to the Search Cell's UITextField, I have a function `searchBarEditingChanged(searchTextField: UITextField)` where after `self.tableView.reloadData()` I call `searchTextField.becomeFirstResponder()`

How can I get around this?

I was considering using a search controller earlier but I didn't like that you have to pull down to make the search bar visible

edit:

tried using this instead

```
    let sectionsToReload = IndexSet(1...sectionHeaders.count)
    self.tableView.reloadSections(sectionsToReload, with: .none)
```

but it crashes on reloadSections: `2017-05-22 15:37:21.600257 MYAPP[565:89501] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.6.22/UITableView.m:1284`

Answer (score 4):

Keep the textfield and the result in two different sections, on search reload only result section. This should work

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`UISearchBar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchbar)—this is what it is for.

Answer (score -2):

view.endEditing(false) in the UITextFieldDelegate method.